# related rates sphere volume and area calculus problem

Tags: calculus

I  have been given the following problem:

A spherical balloon is expanding at the rate of 60 pie in^3/sec. How fast is the surface area of the balloon expanding when the radius of the balloon is 4 inches?

I don't understand how the way I set the problem up is not giving me the correct answer. I have created an equation that links volume to area, did implicit diff. and now I should have only 2 variables, one of which I have the value for, dV/dt.  [please see image for how I set up the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPFZ9.jpg)

Comment: The balloon sure sounds delicious.

Comment: What exactly is your issue with the problem? Are you aware of the answer and yours doesn't match or you think you are missing information?

Comment: thank you for replying. I am aware my answer does not match the supposed correct answer. By my equation you can see in the image embedded above, the area should be increasing by 7.5 in^2/sec. The answer I was given in the text was 30 pi in^2/sec. I understand how the text arrived at that answer, what I don't understand is how my equation didn't provide me the same answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that $$\frac{\mathrm dV}{\mathrm dt} = 4 \pi r^2\cdot \frac{\mathrm dr}{\mathrm dt} =60$$

which implies $$\frac{\mathrm dr}{\mathrm dt} =\frac{60}{4 \pi r^2}$$

We know that $A = 4 \pi r^2$, and so we also have

$$\frac{\mathrm dA}{\mathrm dt} = 8\pi r\cdot \frac{\mathrm dr}{\mathrm dt} $$
Plug in what we found for $\frac{\mathrm dr}{\mathrm dt}$ and plug in $r=4$ to get

$$\frac{\mathrm dA}{\mathrm dt} = 8\pi r\cdot \bigg( \frac{60}{4 \pi r^2}\bigg) $$

$$\frac{\mathrm dA}{\mathrm dt} = \frac{120}r = \frac{120}4$$

$$\frac{\mathrm dA}{\mathrm dt} = 30$$

Answer (score 0):

You want to know $dA/dt$, so rearrange the equation you have for this quantity, substitute in your expression for $A$ as a function of $r$, and finally evaluate at the value of $r$ given.